# Android Studio Error while generating the main dex list

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-glide, wikitude

Im new to android app development, but im building an AR app that also uses glide to choose a piece of artwork from a website and then use the AR to hang in on a wall.

Im getting  "Error while generating the main dex list" and im not sure why.

I had already built the main app and then imported the AR part from wikitude so im wondering if thats creating a conflict.

Im not sure if the best way to show you is to upload the project somewhere and then have someone look through it?

Thanks in advance

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "codingwithmitch.com.recyclerview"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}



dependencies {

implementation (name: 'wikitudesdk', ext:'aar' )
implementation project(':arapp')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
//recyclerview
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
//glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
//circle imageview
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'



}
```

This is for the augmented reality part

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "8.0.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation(name: 'wikitudesdk', ext: 'aar')
implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.1.0'


}

repositories {
flatDir{
    dirs 'libs'
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file? I'm guessing that there is a mismatch in dependencies.

Comment: See edited question. Hopefully this will help. I actually imported an aar file into my app ,so it looks like theres 2 build.gradles.
The top one is the main app and the second one is for the AR part

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this, i'm not sure if it's going to work:

```
//In your app gradle file, inside "android":

dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

//Also in your app gradle file, inside "dependencies":
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
```

Comment: Hey, im still getting the same thing unfortunately, when im trying to build the apk.
Is there something i can post to show you.

Comment: Maybe you can post you build app gradle